# Avoid DBRefs loop in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, jackson, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How to avoid DBRefs loop in Spring Data MongoDB:

```
public class A implements Serialisable {
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private B b;
    ...
}

public class B implements Serialisable {
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private A a;
    ...
}
```

When I'm trying to convert object A to JSON I got the endless loop.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to have separate collection for the documents? It looks like one-to-one relation, why not to embed?

Comment: @AndriySimonov  I'm working on legacy database that's used by other applications :(

Comment: There is a lot of ways for doing that. Depending on your actual needs simple @JsonIgnore could be enough

Comment: @chimmi Strange, but \@JsonIgnore does not help, as well as mixin with \@JsonView.

Comment: Without actual example of how you use it all, I can only suggest to move on the list: there is still filters and custom serializers remain)

Comment: Assuming that you are serializing this data to JSON for the purpose of exposing it on an API, I would suggest you create a set of DTO classes instead.  Exposing your database schema to an external API will almost always cause you problems down the road.